# How to properly replace view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I just can't understand what am i doing wrong with this. I have 2 unrelated view controllers, which i created in `storyboard` by dragging a view controller to screen. each has its name identifier in storyboard and i replace between them by their names.

Problem is ,that after the first replacement i get tens of memory warnings that are unrelated to reality because my memory consumption is about **59M** and stay like that . When i switch from A to B and than back to A, sometimes its crash due to "lake of memory" (59M!! ) .

What am i doing wrong when replacing view controllers ???

```
- (IBAction)goMatrix:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *mainV=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MatrixView"];
    mainV.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:mainV animated:YES completion:^(void)
     {
         scroller.delegate=nil;
         scroller=nil;
         [imagesBuffer removeAllObjects];
         [scroller removeFromSuperview];
         [stripView removeFromSuperview];


     }];

}
```

I have a scrollview in both of them with images, that i just remove from the superview, i just can't understand what else can i do to **REALLY** clean things up (although memory is just 59M )

- the only moment i have high memory is when i replace them, and its 134M for only 1 second(!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your App is a single view structure (without embedded in `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`), you can use:

```
// App Delegate
UIViewController *mainV=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MatrixView"];
self.window.rootViewController = mainV;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
stripView = nil;
```

Old view controller will be automatically be removed from memory if you use ARC.

If you are writing in View Controller, you can use:

```
UIViewController *mainV=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MatrixView"];
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.window.rootViewController = mainV;
[delegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
stripView = nil;
```

Comment: I am not sure i understand what do you mean by "can use" , what do i do with his code? i have to be able to replace from B to A, than from A to B, how would i do that , and what is wrong with my current code ?

Comment: i dont think with storyboard , you need to use setRootViewController or makrKeyAndVisible , bacause storyboard do this for you . just a defined window in appdelegate & return YES in applicationdidfinishlaunching.

Comment: that's incorrect. You can still use these with storyboard.

Comment: and why one get memory warnings for 59M ?

Comment: It really depends on what did you write in your view controller class. Too few information to diagnose.

Comment: And again, what is wrong with my code to replace views?

Comment: What if you write a lot of I/O work in `viewDidUnload`? Think about it. It will cause memory spike. `presentViewController` will cause 2 view controllers appear on screen at the same time, which results in high memory usage. Anything unclear?

Comment: To clarify further, before completion of `presentViewController`, the old view controller still occupies memory, while new view controller is occupying memory too. Also, with `animated:YES`, some memory is spent in `UIAnimation`. To be fast & clean, use my suggested method. *Again, what's wrong about my answer* ?

Comment: @Raptor your answer is great , thanks a lot! what is strange to me is, why Apple has this kind of transition if you say it has a moment of high memory.