# Memory is increasing with transitions?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just can't understand why the transition thing never works as expected from memory aspect.
This is what i know, correct me if i am wrong :

**Every time you switch to a new view controller,and remove the previous, no matter how, using ARC, the system should free ALL memory from previous controller, including  views,instance variables,arrays,and almost anything else.(not using webView)**

Well, it never seems to be even close to that, and i always gets accumulation in memory, means that each view is takes about 30M, and when switching back and forward it becomes 130 after a while .
WHY ???? What else can one do, to be sure **EVERYTHING IS FREE** ?? EVREYTHING ?

This is how i replace views that are created with storyboard,and have a name :
(they both have a scrollview with images, that SHOULD be removed when switching)

```
UIViewController *mainV=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlbumView"];
mainV.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:mainV animated:YES completion:^(void)
 {
     scroller.delegate=nil;
     scroller=nil;
     [scroller removeFromSuperview];//should remove the main memory consumer!
     [self.view removeFromSuperview];


 }];
```

Comment: Check your app in instrument and see what is eating up your memory.

Comment: I had never manage to understand anything from instrument, it shows you so much words that you can't understand how they related to your program, i can't see the specific memory consumption,the array name, the imageView, or what ever it is that i can identify. i could never really use instrument to detect the problem.

Comment: then try harder, without instruments you won't be able to identify where and why memory is used. Reading the values from Xcode is not giving you useful information. Also note that in the simulator memory management is different than on the device. Also note: ARC is not releasing memory all memory for you, you have to use strong, weak and references in the correct way. ARC is not a garbage collector.

Comment: It really hard to understand at the beginning but once you do it it becomes easy to understand what's going on. Whether you like instrument or hate it you have to use it in any case. There is no other option.

Answer (score 1):

`presentViewController` doesn't remove anything. It adds a *new* view controller *on top* of the current one. If you keep doing this, you will end up with a stack of view controllers a mile high, with memory consumption to match.

You need to look into a different structure, probably a custom container view controller which *replaces* its child view controller when you perform certain actions, but without knowing what you are trying to do I can't offer any more advice.

Comment: ok , thanks. what i am trying to do, is to switch between 3 views, made with storyboard ,that each has its own identifier, and they are unrelated to each other .

Comment: You can try setting the window's root view controller to the new one.

Comment: Your answer is not going with another answer i have got here. the user Raptor, wrote to me at the comment for a question ,that the view will actually removed with this, but there will be a just one moment that they will both be on screen. so i keep wondering how is that anyone is saying something else about this code. you can check his comment to his own answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778437/how-to-properly-replace-view-controllers

Comment: His answer is saying what I just said, and I don't see how this isn't a duplicate of that question. You don't seem to be understanding what people are telling you. How is this question not a duplicate?

Comment: And his comment about how presentViewController works is incorrect. The old view controller doesn't get removed from anywhere.

Comment: You're also getting confused between a view controller and a view. If the view controller still exists, it will still have a reference to its view.

Answer (score 0):

Put the line `[scroller removeFromSuperview];` before `scroller=nil`.

Comment: This is not true. the SYSTEM should remove the scroller anyway, even if i don't put 1 line in there. i am not the one who have to remove this things, and i can't understand why the system doesn't do that .

Comment: You are the one who has to give the system a clear indication what to remove e and when by using appropriate references. UI elements, if not referenced strongly elsewhere will be released for you when the superview is released

Comment: @Volker So anything that referenced strong, i must remove my self ??

Comment: It depends if you create circular reference then yes, otherwise if you define a strong property in a class and the class instance is released it will also release its strong properties... if not from somewhere else someone also holds a strong reference onto it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is very simple , if i want to go from A to B i do :

```
 [self presentViewController:mainV animated:YES completion:^(void)
     {

 //dont remove your views here        
     }];
```

And don't remove my views from A .

Than , i want to back from B to A :

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) 

     {

         [allImageView removeAllObjects];
         [imagesAreLoadingNow removeAllObjects];
         [mainData removeAllObjects];
         [scroller removeFromSuperview];
          scroller=nil;
          scroller.delegate=nil;
         [stripView removeFromSuperview];


     }];
```

Which will completely remove B from the stack .

No need to use delegates or other stuff, because i can still let 1 root view stay in the stack .